# Calculate the minimal MOSFET source current needed for 12 TTL MOSFETS

Tags: mosfet, voltage-regulator, current-measurement

This is definitely a beginner question as this is the second PCB I ever designed but you can't learn unless you do something. (It's an optimization of an older board I have to do as project.)

I would like to know how I could calculate the minimal (or best) current needed for my 12 TTL MOSFETs as I am looking for a good power source right now.

I am using [IRLL014](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/427/sihll014-1768836.pdf) MOSFETs, the gates are connected to an [MCP23017](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20001952c.pdf). The signal comes from an ESP32. As these are N-MOSFETs my VDD is 12V.  They have an SSR as load.

If I look into the datasheet I can find \$V_{DS}\$ to \$I_{D}\$, depending on \$V_{GS}\$ - The GS is 5V as it comes from the MCP. So if I look right it should be around 9-10 amperes which sounds insane, as in a worst case scenario I may need to switch ON all the MOSFETs at the same time and drawing 100 amperes sounds just wrong. Obviously I don't need that much but would they work with lower current? If so, how much?

As for why I need a voltage regulator - The input voltage is 24V maximum and needs to be regulated down to 12V for VDD but the highest current with a fair price I found for these is around 3A while everything above is way more expensive.

Could you help me and teach me how to calculate the needed current for my PCB?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHiDK1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I made a simple schematic as an example to make a visual representation (won't work for simulation.)

EDIT:

- [SSR 1](https://www.lirrd.com/products/dc-to-ac-solid-state-relay)
- [SSR 2](https://www.lirrd.com/products/dc-to-ac-3-phase-solid-state-relay)

Pictures of the original schematic:

[image: MOSFET]

[image: Power]

Buzzer comes from the ESP32 directly here.

Comment: According to your "schemantic", there will be a large puff of smoke when you activate any of the MOSFETs.

Comment: Could you tell my why as I followed the original schemantic here and just added the MCP? Cant really see the error because of my knowledge level.

Comment: Add a picture of the original (and the word is) *schematic* and not *schemantic*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were probably looking at this chart when you got that "\$V_{DS}\$ to \$I_{D}\$, depending on \$V_{GS}\$" business that gave you 9 amperes:

[image]

You missed the note in the corner that says "20 microsecond pulse width."

What that chart says is that if you provide a 20 microseconds pulse to the following circuit then there will be 20 microsecond long pulse of the current given in the chart.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fThFuB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That's not a very useful circuit, and that high current rating isn't that useful.

For continuous current, you need to look at the "Absolute Maximum Ratings" which says 2.7A at 25 C.  You also need to look at this chart which gives you information on what it is safe to do for various current and voltage combinations:

[image]

What those charts are trying to tell you is how much current **may** be passed through the transistor under various conditions.

All of that still doesn't solve your real problem, though.

The real problem is that you are doing this with your transistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPfGzj.png)</sup>

That shows a mechanical relay rather than the SSR you intend to use, but it works the same.

There are two problems with your circuit:

1. It takes **two** connections to the relay to make it switch, and you've only provided one.
2. You have your transistor set up to short circuit the power supply.

Your relay circuit needs to look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEGoea.png)</sup>

The relay (whether SSR or mechanical) will limit the current through the transistor - no more than a few 10s of milliamperes will flow for the SSR, maybe a couple of hundred milliamperes if it were a mechanical relay.

Here at last is the answer to your question:

> How much current should your 12V power supply be able to deliver, assuming that all relays may be activated at once.

If you are driving 12 relays, then the answer is "12 times the control current of one relay."

Your linked SSR datasheets both say "less than 10 milliamperes of control current."

A 12V power supply capable of supplying 120 milliamperes would be enough to drive all 12 SSRs at once.

---

You mention in comments that you may need to drive loads directly with the IRLL014.

In that case, your 12V power supply would need to supply enough current for the loads.  Given that the IRLL014 can only handle a couple of amperes continuously, your power supply would need to be able to supply something over 24 amperes continuously.

The circuit would also be a little different:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8W3tg.png)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

SSR’s have an IR optocoupled diode input and therefore may be driven directly without need for a low Ron FET.

- typical SSR If is 4 or  12mA or say 10mA @ 1.2V so from 5V , 380 Ohms would limit the current. subtracting the Vol/Iol of the MCP23017 from parameter D080 is 0.6V/4mA= 120 Ohm worst case at Vdd=4.5V means depending on SSR specs a current limiting R can be 380-120 Ohms.

Comment: Just consulated  with my supervisor - the MOSFET are neccessary because we won't always put SSRs as load so means they could be the load but it's not neccessary.

Comment: You must define R current limit to a worse case load!   If you neglect Vol/Iol from FET <<1 Ohm so R=~ 380 Ohms depending on SSR worst case Iin how can you drive a bigger load? Unless you add dummy Resistors or Select on Test , Interface.

Comment: TTL mosfet? Do you mean 'logic level' mosfet? You're also interpreting the datasheet incorrectly - the mosfet requires a given gate charge/voltage in order to switch a given current. The mosfet itself won't draw that current.

Comment: SSR is undefined for LOAD, I assumed common SSR with IR diode only, which has nothing to do with Logic level FET input voltage as Ron is < 1 Ohm would burn out SSR LED.,unless it was assumed that Rs was added to SSR and FET shunts the LED off, then Pd of Rs must be revised, Too many assumptions and lack of interface specs.